# reordering a factor A by the numeric values of a factor B

Tags: r, forcats

Hi there: I have a data set that looks like this. I my data set, alpha, omega and zeta are the names of issues. Respondents were asked rate a party leader ('Z', 'B' or 'C') as the leader that would best manage that issue.

I would like to show the distribution of responses for each issue, but I would like to see the facets ordered such that the first facet shows the highest percent for a particular party leader (e.g. Z) and then moving down.

In the code below, I specifically chosen variable names that span the length of the alphabet (e.g. alpha to zeta) and not set a seed, because I want to get some code back that *always* orders the levels of the variable Issue such that the first level is the issue that party leader Z scored highest on, and that the second level is the issue that party leader Z scored second-highest on.

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

#In my data set these are issues, like taxes, health, etc. 
alpha<-sample(c('Z', 'B', 'C'), replace=T,size=300)
omega<-sample(c('Z', 'B', 'C'), replace=T,size=300)
zeta<-sample(c('Z', 'B', 'C'), replace=T, size=300)

#make data frame
df<-data.frame(alpha, omega, zeta)

df %>% 
  #gather into an issue variable and a leader variable
  gather(Issue, Leader) %>% 
  #count
  count(Issue, Leader) %>% 
  #form groups for counting percent
  group_by(Issue) %>% 
  #calculate percent
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>%
  #ungroup
  group_by(Leader)%>% 
  #try reordering based on
  mutate(Issue=fct_reorder(Issue, pct, .desc=F)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=Leader, y=pct))+geom_col()+facet_wrap(~Issue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a specific use case, I would find and set the order explicitly:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Issue, Leader) %>% 
  count(Issue, Leader) %>% 
  group_by(Issue) %>% 
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup -> 
  plot_df

issue_order = filter(plot_df, Leader == "Z") %>% 
    arrange(desc(pct)) %>% 
    pull(Issue) %>%
    as.character

plot_df = mutate(plot_df, Issue = factor(Issue, levels = issue_order))

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x=Leader, y=pct))+geom_col()+facet_wrap(~Issue)
```

---

As a side-note, I'd encourage you to improve your comments by avoiding obvious comments. It's good to comment code, but good code (especially `dplyr` code) is pretty well self-documenting. One common comment best practice is *"comment why, not how,"* with the idea that the code tells you *what* happens, comments are needed mostly to explain *why*. Comments like this (below) add no value, and instead break up your meaningful code making it harder to read:

```
#count
count(Issue, Leader) %>%
```

Here, you use a nice variable name for percent, `pct`, so you don't need a comment to tell you what it is:

```
#calculate percent
mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>%
```

Comment: This works great. 1) I will take your advice for the future. 2) What in the heck does `pull()` do???? Never seen that before.  `dplyr` never ceases to amaze.

Comment: Most dplyr functions return a data frame. `pull` is an exception, it pulls the column out of the data frame and returns it as a vector. Compare `str(select(mtcars, mpg))` to `str(pull(mtcars, mpg))`.